# Plotting logarithmic graph (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, math, audio, graph

This is a little tricky,
I'd like to generate some graph lines for a frequency spectrum.

e.g.

[image: Ableton]

See how the x-axis graph lines change logarithmically in this way...

[image]

What i need is the maths to do this above. And then a way to plot x coordinates accurately upon it.

I want to be plotting frequencies between 20Hz to 16000Hz across the x-axis in this way.

*(I'm not too worried about the drawing part I can use canvas, i'm just stuck on the maths)*

I think i would then need a function to convert say 1525Hz into px (or%) to be plotted on it.

Many thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

i'd use something like this (live example on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Aprillion/8kzes/)):

```
var min_f = Math.log(20) / Math.log(10),
    max_f = Math.log(16000) / Math.log(10),
    range = max_f - min_f,
    position_px = (Math.log(frequency) / Math.log(10) - min_f) / range * width_px
```

Comment: Excellent. This works, thank you. At first I thought it would need to be repeated as it looks like there are a few next to each other. But that's not the case, only the unit division change. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you dividing it by Math.log(10)? You could use Math.log(freq, 10) to have it in the base of 10. Also I noticed, that even if you don't divide or even if you change the base from e to anythig, the result is always the same.

Comment: @Ruuza because [`Math.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log) only accepts 1 paremater, you cannot change the base in JS...

Comment: Thanks. And why the base of 10? Seems the result is the same for any base given

Comment: no idea, this answer is from 2012, I probably didn't realize that the answer is independent of base